# Help with a nonhomogeneous function for a boundary value problem

Tags: calculus

I have tried multiple functions but i cant get the correct one for this problem.

Find a function of one variable $y(x)$ such that $y′′(x)=0$, for $0\lt x\lt \pi$, and $y(0)=y(\pi)=0$.

I was thinking that $y(x)=0$ as the answer but I am uncertain because you can also create a piecewise function that follows the same conditions.

Comment: well, $y'$ is constant, i.e. $y = ax + b$, if this has at least two zeroes then it's the zero function (a piecewise linear function isn't differentiable at the peaks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is y(x) = 0. Thank you to @uncookedfalcon19